# From Cookie to <img Src="">

Tags: php, image

I need to know if it is possible to use a php cookie in a html img src?

I have tried servel thing but none of them worked out as i hoped.

If some one could help me that would be great.

```
    <div id="puzzle" style="width: 450px">   <!-- grote van de foto's aanpassen en foto's aanpassen-->
        <img id="image_1" src='puzzelstukjes/1<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_5" src='puzzelstukjes/2<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_7" src='puzzelstukjes/3<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_9" src='puzzelstukjes/4<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_8" src='puzzelstukjes/5<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_4" src='puzzelstukjes/6<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_2" src='puzzelstukjes/7<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_6" src='puzzelstukjes/8<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
        <img id="image_3" src='puzzelstukjes/9<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>' alt=""  width="150" height="200">
    </div>
```

here is a little example of a thing i have tried

```
    <?php
    setcookie("foto2",  $_COOKIE["foto"], time()+3600); 
    ?>
```

this is a example of the cookie is used

Comment: What you have tried? Share the code

Comment: Change `<?php.$_COOKIE["foto2"]?>` to `<?php echo $_COOKIE["foto2"]; ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following

```
<?php
 echo $_COOKIE["foto2"];
 ?>
```